# Converting command-line cURL where URL is piped to python

Tags: php, curl

I have this command-line cURL example:

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: $AUTH_TOKEN" \
     -d "{\"data\":{\"name\":\"Device1 Callflow\", \"numbers\":[\"1001\"], \"flow\":{\"module\":\"device\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"$DEVICE_ID\"}}}}" \
     http://ip.add.re.ss:8000/v2/accounts/$ACCOUNT_ID/callflows | python -mjson.tool
```

My task is to convert this into a PHP function, where the needed values are passed into the function:

function someFunc($AUTH_TOKEN, $ACCOUNT_ID, $DEVICE_ID, $numbers) {}

Normally, I use this sort of code:

```
function setLimits($auth_token, $accountID, $feature1_cnt, $feature2_cnt) {
    $service_url = "http://ip.add.re.ss:8000/v2/accounts/$accountID/limits";
    $data = '{"data":{"feature1": ' . $feature1_cnt . ',"feature2": ' . $feature2_cnt . '}}';
    $ch = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Auth-Token: $auth_token",'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
    }
    $decoded = json_decode($response);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
  }
    return(true);
}
```

BUT, for a specific API call, I need to pass this as the service URL:

http://ip.add.re.ss:8000/v2/accounts/$ACCOUNT_ID/callflows | python -mjson.tool

How do I do that?

Comment: 1. Don't construct JSON by hand, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). 2. `| python -mjson.tool` isn't part of the url, it's bash syntax that directs the output of the curl command into whatever `python -mjson.tool` [a separate command] does. 3. Don't send it back out to python, do whatever it is that that does in PHP or, alternatively, do all of this in python. The point is that mixing languages is generally more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that the source of the original code got back to me on that -mjson.tool It was merely to pretty-print the JSON in a terminal window when running the command. I have no need of that at all. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

First, change:

```
$data = '{"data":{"feature1": ' . $feature1_cnt . ',"feature2": ' . $feature2_cnt . '}}';
```

to:

```
$data = [
    "data" => [
        "feature1" => $feature1_cnt,
        "feature2" => $feature2_cnt
    ]
];
```

You *will* make a mistake typing out JSON, and it *won't* be easy to find or fix.

Second, [`python -mjson.tool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

> json.tool [...] to validate and pretty-print:

PHP's JSON validation is pretty much just checking if [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returned `NULL`, and then you can check [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) for error info. It is not robust.

You can encode JSON in "pretty-printed" format with:

```
json_encode($foo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But I can't think of an earthly reason why you would want to do that other than if there are human eyeballs that are going to be looking at it.

Lastly, in answering your question I've realized that I have no actual idea what you're getting at and you really need to clarify *why* you think you need to do anything you asked about. [other than the validation, I suppose]